# Error al convertir Json a String[] C#

Tags: c#

Un servicio me responde con la siguiente cadena json y quiero convertirla a un string[]:

```
string JSON = "{\"GetResult\":[\"200\",\"300\"]}";
string[] mensaje = new string[2];

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
mensaje = js.Deserialize<string[]>(JSON);

Console.WriteLine(mensaje[1]);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

> No hay ningún constructor sin parámetros definido para el tipo de 'System.String[]'.

¿Cómo podría convertir el json a un `string[]`?

Comment: Si te fijas la propiedad `GetResult` es la que es un array que esta contenida en un objeto, ese es el problema, no puedes deserializar un objeto y tratar de meterlo en un array

Comment: [Acá puedes encontrar un ejemplo](https://rextester.com/SFEPB28628) funcional de lo que deseas lograr ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te esta faltando la propiedad `GetResult`que contiene el array, si usas

http://json2csharp.com/

para obtener la clase a la cual deserializar, obtienes:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<string> GetResult { get; set; }
}
```

Usa la libreria `json.net` para deserializar

[Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

Entonces quedaria

```
string JSON = "{\"GetResult\":[\"200\",\"300\"]}";
RootObject mensaje = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

foreach(var item in mensaje.GetResult){
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Gracias, ya funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Es por la estructura a la cual quieres desserializae. Es altamente recomendable usar una clase DTO para las estructuras de [JSON](https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/Como-usar-JSON-en-NET-facilmente.aspx).

```
class DeserializadaDTO{
    public string[] GetResult;
}

    string JSON = "{\"GetResult\":[\"200\",\"300\"]}";
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var mensaje = js.Deserialize<DeserializadaDTO>(JSON);

    Console.WriteLine(mensaje.GetResult[1]);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

El tener una estructura clase.array[string] es distinta a tener un array[string];